# Use jquery's $.ajax to get a node.js script's output, not its code

Tags: ajax, node.js, jquery

I am building a small prototype, and have the following problem:

I am trying to communicate between client-side jQuery, and server-side node.js; when I make a jQuery ajax request to my node.js code, it just gives me the code, not the output of the code.

What am I doing wrong?

**Part of client.js:**

```
$.ajax({url      : './../includes/get_data.js', 
        success  : function(data) {
          alert('success!');
        },
        error    : function(data) {
          alert('error!');
        }
});
```

**get_data.js:**

```
var fs = require('fs');

console.log('test');
```

When I make a request to get_data.js, the output I want is:
    test

But instead I get the source code:

```
var fs = require('fs');

console.log('test');
```

Many thanks

Comment: How is your server-side node.js environment set up? From what I see, you're trying to access it as a CGI script, which is not how node.js is usually employed.

Comment: Hmm... checking into this right now.  I probably just need to make it so that my server executes the code, then sends it back :P.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're just asking for a static .js file, you're not interacting with Node at all. If you want to do so, make an HTTP server (copy the example on http://nodejs.org/), bind it to a port and write a response back, don't use console.log (which will only output to the console).

Example:

Save the following file as app.js and then run it in the terminal with `node app.js` then visit localhost on port 1337:

```
var http = require('http'),
    ajaxResponse = { 'hello': 'world' },
    htmlContent;

htmlContent  = "<html><title></title><head>";
htmlContent += "<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>";
htmlContent += "<script>$(function() {$.ajax({url:'/ajax',success:function(data){alert('success!');console.log(data);},error:function(data){alert('error!');}});});</script>";
htmlContent += "</head><body><h1>Hey there</h1>";
htmlContent +="</body></html>";

http.createServer(function (req, res) {   
  if (req.url === '/ajax') {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/json'});
    res.end(JSON.stringify(ajaxResponse));
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(htmlContent);  
  }  
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Checking into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want a GET a certain URL on your server (running Node) that in turn executes the code in get_data.js on your server?

If so, use express - look at http://expressjs.com/api.html#express.

- In your Node Express's app.get() ...

  1. First arg - Supply the route you want (e.g., '/mygetdata').
  2. Second arg - In this callback function, call your get_data.js code
- In your client code, modify it to request the URL (e.g., 'http://mywebsite.com/mygetdata'), instead of get_data.js.