# Node js works fine but how do I get it on browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a table in sql Server and I am trying to display it in web browser and apply datatable(jQuery) to it. Below code works fine as it gives the output in command line. But I'd have to get it on the browser(probably in json format).
I am using 'tedious' for connection as that's what I found in Express.js documentation.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;

var config = {
userName: 'clientinfo', 
password: 'clientinfo123', 
server: 'USW20051234'
}
var connection = new Connection(config);

connection.on('connect', function (err) {
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
} else {
    executeStatement();
}
});

function executeStatement() {
request = new Request("SELECT * from dbo.Logs", function (err, rowCount) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(rowCount+' rows');

    }
    connection.close();
});

request.on('row', function (columns) {
    columns.forEach(function (column) {
        if (column.value === null) {
            console.log('NULL');
        } else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(column.value));
        }
    });
});

connection.execSql(request);
}
```

Comment: `But I'd have to get it on the browser` - look up AJAX

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32195310/pass-data-through-to-the-view-in-express

Comment: @Jaromanda I looked up for AJAX and found the below code which works fine. Still kinda confused, how do I merge my code with AJAX code so that it shows the table on the browser.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10721755/6069038

Comment: `merge my code with AJAX code` - I thought the code in the question was server side code - so called AJAX code is in the browser - you don't "merge" anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You everyone for all the suggestions. I think "tedious" was giving me a hard time so I did npm install mssql and that worked like a charm.
Below is the link I referred to.
http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/access-sql-server-in-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

You need to start HTTP server. As you already define APP try this

```
app.get('/urltest', (req, res) => {
   res.send('hello from nodejs');
});

const PORT =  5000;
app.listen(PORT);
console.log('Listening on :' + PORT + '...');
```

and try http:localhost:5000/urltest on a browser